# subtract one column from multiple columns in the same dataframe using method chaining

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

I have a dataframe in pandas and I would like to subtract one column (lets say `col1`) from `col2` and `col3` (or from more columns if there are) without writing the the below assign statement for each column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4], 'col2':[2,5,6,8], 'col3':[5,5,5,9]})

df = (df
     ...
     .assign(col2 = lambda x: x.col2 - x.col1)
     )
```

How can I do this? Or would it work with apply? How would you be able to do this with method chaining?

Comment: @anky: I haven't seen your comment while I was composing and testing the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: *(using `**kwarg` with chainning method)*

As in your comment, if you want to chain method on the intermediate(on-going calculated) dataframe, you need to define a custom dictionary to calculate each column to use with `assign` as follows (you can't use lambda to directly construct dictionary inside `assign`).

In this example I do `add` 5 to the dataframe before chaining `assign` to show how it works on chain processing as you want

```
d = {cl: lambda x, cl=cl: x[cl] - x['col1'] for cl in ['col2','col3']}
df_final = df.add(5).assign(**d)

In [63]: df
Out[63]:
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     2     5
1     2     5     5
2     3     6     5
3     4     8     9

In [64]: df_final
Out[64]:
   col1  col2  col3
0     6     1     4
1     7     3     3
2     8     3     2
3     9     4     5
```

**Note**: `df_final.col1` is different from `df.col1` because of the `add` operation before `assign`. Don't forget `cl=cl` in the lambda of dictionary. *It is there to avoid late-binding issue of python*.

---

Use `df.sub`

```
df_sub = df.assign(**df[['col2','col3']].sub(df.col1, axis=0).add_prefix('sub_'))

Out[22]:
   col1  col2  col3  sub_col2  sub_col3
0     1     2     5         1         4
1     2     5     5         3         3
2     3     6     5         3         2
3     4     8     9         4         5
```

If you want to assign values back to `col2`, `col3`, use additional `update`

```
df.update(df[['col2','col3']].sub(df.col1, axis=0))

print(df)

Output:
    col1  col2  col3
0     1     1     4
1     2     3     3
2     3     3     2
3     4     4     5
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, but how would I do it if I have stuff written before. So using method chaining? So instead of using df using lambda x: ..x[['col2', 'col3']]

Comment: @corianne1234: you can't use `lambda` to directly create `**kwarg` inside `assign`. You need to create a custom dictionary using lambda. I edited the answer to show it. Check my edited answer